# How can I undo .bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-foxpro

I made a HUGE mistake by executing a .bat file, and it changed some files in my folder, especifically from Microsoft Visual Fox pro 5.0, which uses some .dbf, .cdx, .dll, etc., so yeah, is kind of important

```
copy %1*.exe %2*.exe
copy %1pueblos.* %2pueblos.*
copy %1usuario.dbf %2usuario.dbf
copy %1usuario.cdx %2usuario.cdx
copy %1grupos.dbf %2grupos.dbf
copy %1grupos.cdx %2grupos.cdx
copy %1configuracion.dbf %2configuracion.dbf
copy %1*.dbc %2*.dbc
copy %1*.dct %2*.dct
copy %1*.dll %2*.dll
copy %1*.adx %2*.adx
copy %1*.cdt %2*.cdt
```

is there a way that I can undo these changes?

thank you in advance

Comment: You replace the damaged files with the ones you backed up before breaking them. You did that, right? Right?

Comment: You may be able to recover Fox pro with a utility, happens to all of us.. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=388745

Comment: I’m not capable to understanding why people here sometimes don’t see the oblivious solution to the things like this!

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understood the case..,

Why not simple invert the command line argument passed to the bat file again, but change this time:

> **%1 to %2**, and the **%2 to %1** by:

```
copy %2*.exe %1*.exe
copy %2pueblos.* %1pueblos.*
copy %2usuario.dbf %1usuario.dbf
copy %2usuario.cdx %1usuario.cdx
copy %2grupos.dbf %1grupos.dbf
copy %2grupos.cdx %1grupos.cdx
copy %2configuracion.dbf %1configuracion.dbf
copy %2*.dbc %1*.dbc
copy %2*.dct %1*.dct
copy %2*.dll %1*.dll
copy %2*.adx %1*.adx
copy %2*.cdt %1*.cdt
```

**obs.:** So sorry my limited English!

Comment: This will work if the `%2*.exe` files didn't exist before he ran the .bat file.